# Как менять Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Привет, есть две кнопки с текстом каким-нибудь. Нужно чтобы  при нажатии первой кнопки менялось содержимое Navigation Drawer. И тоже самое со второй кнопкой. Как это можно реализовать?
P.S. Использую шаблон от Гугла

Answer (score 1):

1. Получите ссылку на `NavigationView`

   ```
   NavigationView nV = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.NavigationView_ID);
   ```
2. Меняйте его элементы по их ID

   ```
   nV.getMenu().findItem(navigationDrawerItemId).setTitle("newTitle");
   ```